# Angular form validation inherit disabled status from parent control

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have big form with multi input in multi child component. I creat new form group (no control) in parent and pass it into child, in child component, i was set other control.
In my case, i want in parent i can disable all input, but when set control in child can not inherit disable status.

How i can do it?

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjk44y

P/s: excuse me my English.

Comment: Please post code to demonstrate your problem

Comment: demo link has been added

Comment: When you call `disable` on root FormGroup it doesn't include all your child controls yet. Since `disable` method iterates over controls you have to wait until they are registered https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcpu6q?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: thank your comment, new link demo has been updated.
In case call service and so can not use AfterViewInit, i am try AfterViewChecked but not working